# React Native + Expo not working background location in some devices

Tags: react-native, push-notification, geolocation, location, expo

I have an Android app that its built with React Native + Expo. My Expo is currently in version **39.0.0**.
The user starts a location service by clicking in a button and when users changes position the app with its new position execute some rules based on location and show some **notifications** depending of user position.

Everything works great when the app is in foreground, in every tested devices. But, when the app goes to background it stops to work in some devices.

For example, in Xiaomi devices the app works great but in Samsung don't. =[

Can anyone help me?

Here`s part of my "app.json":

```
"android": {
  "package": "br.i.dont.know.whats.going.on",
  "versionCode": 86,
  "permissions": [
    "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
    "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
    "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION",
    "CAMERA",
    "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "NOTIFICATIONS",
    "USER_FACING_NOTIFICATIONS",
    "FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
  ],
```

This is the location task registered when app starts:

```
export async function registerFetchTask() {
  TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK, async ({ data: { locations }, error }) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return;
    }
    const [location] = locations;
    try {
      if (location) {
        AppState.currentState === "background" && updateChart(location);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error while getting user location: ", err);
    }
  });

  const status = await BackgroundFetch.getStatusAsync();
  switch (status) {
    case BackgroundFetch.Status.Restricted:
    case BackgroundFetch.Status.Denied:
      console.log("Background execution is disabled");
      return;

    default: {
      console.debug("Background execution allowed");

      let tasks = await TaskManager.getRegisteredTasksAsync();
      if (tasks.find(f => f.taskName === LOCATION_TASK) == null) {
        console.log("Registering task");
        await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(LOCATION_TASK);

        tasks = await TaskManager.getRegisteredTasksAsync();
        console.debug("Registered tasks", tasks);
      } else {
        console.log(`Task ${LOCATION_TASK} already registered, skipping`);
      }

      console.log("Setting interval to", 5);
      await BackgroundFetch.setMinimumIntervalAsync(5);
    }
  }
}
```

Task location started when user press the button

```
await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
      timeInterval: 5000,
      distanceInterval: 1, // minimum change (in meters) betweens updates
      deferredUpdatesTimeout: 5000,
      deferredUpdatesInterval: 5000, // minimum interval (in milliseconds) between updates
      // foregroundService is how you get the task to be updated as often as would be if the app was open
      foregroundService: {
        notificationTitle: 'App is using your location',
        notificationBody: 'To turn off, go back to the app.',
      },
    });
```

Comment: Did you solve this?